# JSON / MySQL : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to insert JSON values ​​into a MySQL table

I have my ***JSON*** file:

```
[{"order":{"id":"B4589B26","status_order_id":5,"status_order_name":"Sent","customer_id":326
"order_products":[{"order_product {"id":96218,"order_id":96538,"product_id":59320,}}],"customer_email":"user@gmail.com","customer_company":"SARL","customer_name":"user user", .....
```

and here is my ***Python*** code:

```
token = "xxxx"

r = requests.get('url', auth=('user@gmail.com', token))

mydb = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd='user',
db='ytm_db')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

json_obj = r.json()

for ord in json_obj["order"]:
   print("id:", ord["id"])
   print("status_id:", ord["status_order_id"])
   print('---')
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_test (id, status_order_id, customer_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (ord["id"], ord["status_order_id"], ord["customer_id"]))

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print ("Done")
```

but I get this error:

> for ord in json_obj["order"]: TypeError: list indices must be integers
>   or slices, not str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON object is a list of orders, so you can't treat it as a dict by accessing its `"order"` key.

Instead, you should loop through the list of orders and then access the order as a dict:

```
for ord in json_obj:
   print("id:", ord["order"]["id"])
   print("status_id:", ord["order"]["status_order_id"])
   print('---')
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_test (id, status_order_id, customer_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (ord["order"]["id"], ord["order"]["status_order_id"], ord["order"]["customer_id"]))
```